# Ghost detection at the level of equations of motion

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, stability, classical-field-theory, ghosts

My question is about how to detect ghostly degrees of freedom at the level of equations of motion. It is not clear for me how does this work. Let me explain with an example:

Consider the following Lagrangian density for a vector field (I use mostly minus convention):
$$
\mathcal{L}_{kin}= -\frac{1}{2}\partial_aA_b \partial^aA^b .
$$
From the (Poincaré) field-theoretical point of view, this kinetic term leads to 4 degrees of freedom:
$$
\square A^a = 0
$$
(these are 4 Lorentz scalars, a degenerate case of the (spin-0) + (spin-1) splitting). Formulated in this way the 4 scalars are of course decoupled, but you can include an interaction term to $\mathcal{L}_{kin}$ between $A_a$ and other healthy fields.

This theory is known to propagate a ghostly mode. Indeed, if we perform the 3+1 decomposition of the field $A_a=(\phi, B_i)$, we find that the temporal component of $A_a$ has the wrong sign in the kinetic term:
$$
\mathcal{L}_{kin} = \frac{1}{2} \delta^{ij} \dot{B}_i \dot{B}_j - \frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2 +\text{(terms without time derivatives)}
$$

However, when computing the equations of motion, we simply get a Klein-Gordon equation with some inhomogeneous part (interactions). Surely the information about the ghostly propagation must be hidden somehow in the interactions. **My question is: how to detect it?**

At the level of the action one just finds that there is a wrong sign in the kinetic term of $\phi$ and that indicates the presence of a ghost in the leading order (quadratic) Lagrangian. But, **how does one know whether there is a ghost or not just by looking at some set of dynamical equations?**

---

**Practical application**

I normally see these kinds of instability analyses performed at the level of the action for this reason, but, at the same time, this is usually more involved. For example, in the context of perturbative stability, one should go to quadratic (!) order in perturbations, drop boundary terms (which is usually very messy) and then check the signs. At the level of the equations, the same information should be there at linear (!) order in perturbations.

---

**Some thoughts**

I think the key point is to find the Hessian matrix (or *kinetic matrix*) in the equations. If you take the action as it is and compute the variations, the *wrong* sign continues appearing at the level of equations:
$$
  -\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi} = -\dot{\phi}^2 +... ,\qquad -\frac{\delta S}{\delta B_i} =  \delta^{ij}\dot{B}_j +...
$$
Notice that the *matrix of the second-order time derivative sector* (MSO) coincides with the Hessian. But one should be careful and not doing any other manipulations (e.g., since these are just equations, one can multiply them by $-1$, and that would change one row in the MSO so it does not coincide with the Hessian anymore). The problem of this is that I am using information about the Lagrangian (!). What if I just have a set of second-order differential equations?

Observe also that if there is a mixed kinetic term between two fields (a term $\sim \dot{\varphi}\dot{\psi}$) this gives an off-diagonal element in the Hessian matrix. In this case if you multiply one equation by $-1$, then the MSO will not be symmetric. A non-symmetric MSO also seems to be telling you that you cannot trust the signs you see in it to detect ghosts, because such matrix cannot be the Hessian (which is symmetric by definition).